# Why doesn't WPA handshake occur?

Tags: wifi, wpa

```
[root@notebook /opt/aircrack-ng] dmesg -C
[root@notebook /opt/aircrack-ng] aireplay-ng --test wlan0
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Device or resource busy

ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead.  Make
sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start wlan0 <#>'
Sysfs injection support was not found either.

[root@notebook /opt/aircrack-ng] dmesg
[37950.649811] wlan0: deauthenticating from 92:f6:52:f5:aa:d9 by local choice (reason=3)
[37950.664362] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[37950.664371] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[37950.664697] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[37950.672526] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
[37950.672531] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[37950.672533] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[37950.672536] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[37950.672539] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[37950.672541] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[37950.672543] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[37950.672546] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[root@notebook /opt/aircrack-ng]
```

I alread did

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

**My question**: since the test failed, I never get a "WPA handshake" when using "airodump-ng". What am I missing? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. How can I succeed at the test and make a WPA handshake? Using other driver? I tried two wireless cards: an USB stick: "050d:705e" and a built-in "Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)"

UPDATE: there isn't any dmesg messages when using: airodump-ng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is based on two parts:

1 - you have to have a wireless card that supports packet injection. Mine wasn't good, so I bough a TL-WN722N*.

2- The channel needs to be set when starting in monitor mode (even with the TL-WN722N):

```
airmon-ng start wlan0 1
```

*-> additional info: The TL-WN722N that works uses ath9k driver, and lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
```